# use Javascript to render a table out of data serialized using RDF

Tags: javascript, rdf, semantic-web

What I want is a function that can output data in a table, like so:

[image]

As a starting point I have the following [data table code](https://gist.github.com/jfreels/6814721), it can make exactly what's pictures above from CSV of the form:

```
"variable","aror","asd","maxdd"
"Convertible Arbitrage",0.0770203710991655,0.0694461870173684,-0.292688394529575
"CTA Global",0.0767109922711062,0.0870559916457339,-0.11676813742079
"Distressed Securities",0.0975096216543971,0.0635590261337229,-0.229232535454022
"Emerging Markets",0.0936124939942315,0.133615370977481,-0.359789528051813
```

To make that it uses this function:

```
function drawDataTableFromDsv(dataFile, fileDelimiter, suppressedHeaders, outputElementId) {

  var dsv = d3.dsv(fileDelimiter, "text/utf-8");  // plain
  dsv(dataFile, function(error, data) {
        if (error)
            return console.error(error);

    var dataHeaders = d3.keys(data[0]);
    dataHeaders = _.difference(dataHeaders, suppressedHeaders);
            console.log(dataHeaders)

        data.forEach(function (d, i) {
            //2015-05-13T01:21:07
            if (d.datePosted.trim() != "")
                d.datePosted = isoDateFormat.parse(d.datePosted);
        });

        tabulate(data, dataHeaders, outputElementId);
    });
}
```

So far so good, *but* here is where things get interesting...

I don't care much about that data, what I care about is a file of [RDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework), that looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<rdf:RDF
xmlns:owl='http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#'
xmlns:edsa='http://www.edsa-project.eu/edsa#'
xmlns:pp='ftp://ftp-sop.inria.fr/wimmics/soft/pprint/'
xmlns:kg='http://ns.inria.fr/edelweiss/2010/kgram/'
xmlns:schema='http://schema.org/'
xmlns:geo='http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#'
xmlns:xml='http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace'
xmlns:rdfs='http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#'
xmlns:rdf='http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#'
xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#'
xmlns:cos='http://www.inria.fr/acacia/corese#'
xmlns:geonames='http://www.geonames.org/ontology#'>

<rdf:Description rdf:about='http://sws.geonames.org/2867714/'>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='tl'>Lungsod ng M&#252;nchen</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='rm'>Minca</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='pfl'>Minche</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='bar'>Minga</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='bs'>Minhen</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='hbs'>Minhen</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='lv'>Minhene</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='lt'>Miunchenas</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='cs'>Mnichov</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='hsb'>Mnichow</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='sk'>Mn&#237;chov</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='pl'>Monachium</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='sc'>Monaco de Baviera</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='vec'>Monaco de Baviera</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='it'>Monaco di Baviera</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='nap'>Monaco e Baviera</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='co'>Monacu di Baviera</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='la'>Monacum</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='uz'>Munhen</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='ca'>Munic</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='oc'>Munic</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='ast'>Munich</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='br'>Munich</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='en'>Munich</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='eu'>Munich</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='fr'>Munich</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='ilo'>Munich</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='ms'>Munich</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='nah'>Munich</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='pam'>Munich</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='sco'>Munich</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='tl'>Munich</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='tum'>Munich</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='war'>Munich</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='yo'>Munich</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='tet'>Munike</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='pt'>Munique</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='diq'>Munix</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='eo'>Munkeno</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='ku'>Mun&#238;h</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='sq'>Mynihu</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='ug'>Myunx&#233;n</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='scn'>M&#242;nacu</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='pms'>M&#249;nich &#235;d Baviera</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='gl'>M&#250;nic</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='an'>M&#250;nich</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='es'>M&#250;nich</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='ext'>M&#250;nich</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='gn'>M&#250;nich</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='af'>M&#252;nchen</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='br'>M&#252;nchen</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='da'>M&#252;nchen</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='de'>M&#252;nchen</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='et'>M&#252;nchen</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='fi'>M&#252;nchen</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='hr'>M&#252;nchen</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='hu'>M&#252;nchen</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='id'>M&#252;nchen</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='io'>M&#252;nchen</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='is'>M&#252;nchen</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='nds'>M&#252;nchen</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='nl'>M&#252;nchen</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='nn'>M&#252;nchen</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='no'>M&#252;nchen</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='pdc'>M&#252;nchen</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='ro'>M&#252;nchen</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='sl'>M&#252;nchen</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='sv'>M&#252;nchen</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='vi'>M&#252;nchen</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='vo'>M&#252;nchen</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='lmo'>M&#252;negh</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='az'>M&#252;nhen</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='tr'>M&#252;nih</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='el'>&#924;&#972;&#957;&#945;&#967;&#959;</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='be'>&#1043;&#1086;&#1088;&#1072;&#1076; &#1052;&#1102;&#1085;&#1093;&#1077;&#1085;</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='mk'>&#1052;&#1080;&#1085;&#1093;&#1077;&#1085;</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='sr'>&#1052;&#1080;&#1085;&#1093;&#1077;&#1085;</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='bg'>&#1052;&#1102;&#1085;&#1093;&#1077;&#1085;</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='cv'>&#1052;&#1102;&#1085;&#1093;&#1077;&#1085;</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='kk'>&#1052;&#1102;&#1085;&#1093;&#1077;&#1085;</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='mhr'>&#1052;&#1102;&#1085;&#1093;&#1077;&#1085;</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='mn'>&#1052;&#1102;&#1085;&#1093;&#1077;&#1085;</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='os'>&#1052;&#1102;&#1085;&#1093;&#1077;&#1085;</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='ru'>&#1052;&#1102;&#1085;&#1093;&#1077;&#1085;</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='tg'>&#1052;&#1102;&#1085;&#1093;&#1077;&#1085;</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='uk'>&#1052;&#1102;&#1085;&#1093;&#1077;&#1085;</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='tt'>&#1052;&#1199;&#1085;&#1093;&#1077;&#1085;</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='sah'>&#1052;&#1199;&#1085;&#1093;&#1101;&#1085;</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='mrj'>&#1052;&#1265;&#1085;&#1093;&#1077;&#1085;</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='hy'>&#1348;&#1397;&#1400;&#1410;&#1398;&#1389;&#1381;&#1398;</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='he'>&#1502;&#1497;&#1504;&#1499;&#1503;</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='yi'>&#1502;&#1497;&#1504;&#1499;&#1503;</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='fa'>&#1605;&#1608;&#1606;&#1740;&#1582;</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='ar'>&#1605;&#1610;&#1608;&#1606;&#1582;</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='arz'>&#1605;&#1610;&#1608;&#1606;&#1610;&#1582;</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='ckb'>&#1605;&#1740;&#1608;&#1606;&#1582;</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='pnb'>&#1605;&#1740;&#1608;&#1606;&#1582;</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='ur'>&#1605;&#1740;&#1608;&#1606;&#1582;</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='mr'>&#2350;&#2381;&#2351;&#2369;&#2344;&#2381;&#2358;&#2375;&#2344;</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='hi'>&#2350;&#2381;&#2351;&#2370;&#2344;&#2367;&#2326;</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='bn'>&#2478;&#2495;&#2441;&#2472;&#2495;&#2454;</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='ta'>&#2990;&#3007;&#2991;&#3010;&#2985;&#3007;&#2965;&#3021;</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='kn'>&#3246;&#3277;&#3247;&#3266;&#3240;&#3263;&#3221;&#3277;</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='th'>&#3617;&#3636;&#3623;&#3609;&#3636;&#3585;</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='my'>&#4121;&#4156;&#4144;&#4152;&#4116;&#4101;&#4154;&#4097;&#4155;&#4154;&#4121;&#4156;&#4141;&#4143;&#4151;</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='ka'>&#4315;&#4312;&#4323;&#4316;&#4334;&#4308;&#4316;&#4312;</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='xmf'>&#4315;&#4312;&#4323;&#4316;&#4334;&#4308;&#4316;&#4312;</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='ja'>&#12511;&#12517;&#12531;&#12504;&#12531;</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='zh'>&#24917;&#23612;&#40657;</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:alternateName xml:lang='ko'>&#48012;&#54760;</geonames:alternateName>
 <geonames:countryCode rdf:datatype='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string'>DE</geonames:countryCode>
 <geonames:featureClass rdf:resource='http://www.geonames.org/ontology#P'/>
 <geonames:featureCode rdf:resource='http://www.geonames.org/ontology#P.PPLA'/>
 <geonames:locationMap rdf:resource='http://www.geonames.org/2867714/munich.html'/>
 <geonames:name rdf:datatype='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string'>Munich</geonames:name>
 <geonames:nearbyFeatures rdf:resource='http://sws.geonames.org/2867714/nearby.rdf'/>
 <geonames:parentCountry rdf:resource='http://sws.geonames.org/2921044/'/>
 <geonames:population rdf:datatype='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string'>1260391</geonames:population>
 <geonames:wikipediaArticle rdf:resource='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munich'/>
 <rdf:type rdf:resource='http://www.geonames.org/ontology#Feature'/>
 <rdfs:isDefinedBy rdf:resource='http://sws.geonames.org/2867714/about.rdf'/>
 <rdfs:seeAlso rdf:resource='http://dbpedia.org/resource/Munich'/>
 <geo:lat rdf:datatype='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string'>48.13743</geo:lat>
 <geo:long rdf:datatype='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string'>11.57549</geo:long>
</rdf:Description>

<rdf:Description rdf:about='http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/94342/engineering-systems-data-engineer-arm-ltd'>
 <schema:datePosted rdf:datatype='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#Date'>2015-09-03T09:43:33+00:00</schema:datePosted>
 <schema:datePosted rdf:datatype='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#Date'>2015-09-03T09:43:34+00:00</schema:datePosted>
 <schema:description rdf:datatype='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string'>&lt;p&gt;The Engineering Systems Analytics group is responsible for ensuring that we have a solid understanding of both our engineering infrastructure, which we refer to as the engineering systems stack, and the engineering processes that run on top of it.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;p&gt;It strives to achieve this goal through a number of parallel activities:&lt;/p&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;ul&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;li&gt;By helping to refine our spark-based infrastructure that allows relevant data to be centrally collected, aggregated, and processed&lt;/li&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;li&gt;By developing dashboards, reports and complex analysis and/or visualisations of the data that satisfy the business needs, both in terms of project reporting to help measure progress of the work, and in terms of infrastructure reporting to help understand the impact of this work on the estate&lt;/li&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;li&gt;By working with engineering and IT functions to ensure sufficient relevant data is being captured to provide the best information in the above two categories&lt;/li&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;p&gt;We are looking to augment the team with broad additional skills across the areas listed above.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;p&gt;You will be a software engineer with experience of Spark and R, or equivalents.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;p&gt;You will be equally at home working on the data processing pipeline, or performing an in depth analysis of the data it contains.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;p&gt;You will consider yourself a data scientist, keen to tackle the problems of extracting knowledge from data, and driven to understand the core &amp;lsquo;stories&amp;rsquo; that data can tell, and to help drive efficiency and effectiveness improvements by providing the means to make data driven decisions.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;p&gt;This role be based from ARM&apos;s HQ in Cambridge, UK.&lt;/p&gt;</schema:description>
 <schema:hiringOrganization rdf:datatype='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string'>ARM Ltd</schema:hiringOrganization>
 <schema:jobLocation rdf:datatype='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string'>Cambridge, UK</schema:jobLocation>
 <schema:jobTitle rdf:datatype='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string'>Engineering Systems Data Engineer at ARM Ltd (Cambridge, UK)</schema:jobTitle>
 <schema:source rdf:datatype='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string'>StackOverflow</schema:source>
 <schema:url rdf:resource='http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/94342/engineering-systems-data-engineer-arm-ltd'/>
 <edsa:Location rdf:resource='http://sws.geonames.org/2653941/'/>
 <edsa:requiresSkill rdf:resource='http://www.edsa-project.eu/skill/apache-spark'/>
 <edsa:requiresSkill rdf:resource='http://www.edsa-project.eu/skill/hadoop'/>
 <edsa:requiresSkill rdf:resource='http://www.edsa-project.eu/skill/r'/>
 <edsa:requiresSkill rdf:resource='http://www.edsa-project.eu/skill/sql'/>
</rdf:Description>
```

Will I be able to generalize that function to accept RDF data and output it in a similar style table?

I've been looking into rdfstore-js, but I haven't been able to actually get this working.

Comment: try this http://www.jibbering.com/rdf-parser/

Comment: @mCube Hi, thank you for the recommendation. At the risk of overextending my welcome, do you have any advice on how to handle [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33791217/how-to-tweak-this-javascript-file-to-read-in-my-data-on-localhost-parsing-rdf-t)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd end up with something more maintainable and extendable if you put the data in an RDF database and query it to get back the data you want to render.

Then for your current use case, you can just ask for the results in CSV or TSV format via the SPARQL protocol.

Comment: someone also recommended me to use JSON LD, since D3 is using JSON. What do you think about that?

Comment: That's a great approach, that's exactly what we did for the webconsole of our database

Comment: can I see how it looks like? Do you have a link to it?